# How should I initialize "npm" package in Notepad++?

Tags: javascript, html, css, package, npm-install

I can't initialize the **npm** package in *Notepad++*. I don't know how to do it, because in every video the Youtubers initialize them with the program's **terminal**, but I think Notepad++ doesn't have a terminal or if it does I can't find it. Can anyone help me please, cause I can't finish my Login system if I don't have that package? Or should I use another program for example *Visual Studio*? What's the best HTML development program?

Comment: simply use any other CLI Host / Terminal. For Example: Command Prompt, Powershell, Bash etc.

Comment: You do not need to use Notepad++ to initialize npm - you can use the OS's own console or terminal.  Please read our [ask] page for tips on how to improve this question

Comment: Yeah, actually I already did. I don't know, what did I do wrong, so please clue me in. What points did I miss?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. Open Terminal or Command Prompt if you are using windows.
2. go to the folder where your project is using cd command.
3. Install npm's you need.

The terminal in any code editor is same as operating system terminal.

I will suggest to use VS Code for learning as most tutorials will be using that.